# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: connection closed

Tags: android, kotlin, https, http-headers

When the internet speed is weak or when I use VPN, the connection is disconnected

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: connection closed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:363)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:243)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:220)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at me.unique.map.unique.data.service.WayInterceptor.intercept(WayInterceptor.kt:26)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:221)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
        Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: connection closed
            ... 27 more
        Caused by: java.io.EOFException: connection closed
            ... 26 more
        Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: connection closed
            ... 27 more
        Caused by: java.io.EOFException: connection closed
            ... 26 more
        Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: connection closed
            ... 27 more
        Caused by: java.io.EOFException: connection closed
            ... 26 more
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@e3a8652, Dispatchers.IO]
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: connection closed
        ... 26 more
```

```
class WayInterceptor() : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request :Response
       
            val newRequest = chain
                .request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")

            signatures.forEachIndexed { index, signature ->
                newRequest.addHeader("sig${index}", signature)
            }

            request = chain.proceed(newRequest.build())
            return request
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.